# Meteor auto-close html tags

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

Got strange problem.
When I try to use unclosed html in Handlebars templates - it force closes them when renders.

For example I want to use {{#each items}} with this template:

```
    {{#if a}}
       <li>
    {{/if}}

    {{#if b}}
      </li>
       <li>
    {{/if}}

    {{someItemText}}
```

expectations:

```
    <!--here 'a' from template is true-->
    <li>
       someItemtext from item #1 
       someItemtext from item #2
       someItemtext from item #3 
    <!--here 'b' from template is true-->
    </li>
    <li>
       someItemtext from item #4
       someItemtext from item #5
       someItemtext from item #6
```

renders:

```
    <!--here 'a' from template is true-->
    <li>
       someItemtext from item #1 
    </li>
       someItemtext from item #2
       someItemtext from item #3
    <!--here 'b' from template is true-->
    <li></li>
       someItemtext from item #4
       someItemtext from item #5
       someItemtext from item #6
```

Any ideas how to turn off this force tag close? Thanks!

Comment: I have some_list.html (main page) which got helper that catches all items from collection to iterate them in some_item.html template. which I want to group, using conditionals and opened/closed elements to group.  This template got Template.helpers to check if index is 0 and every n-th. They are working fine. i got true or false if I use them without Handlebars.helpers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Rendering in Meteor is based on DOM nodes, so an `each` block can't output partial nodes. You have to calculate the groups in advance and provide a way to get items per group:

```
{{#each groups}}
  <li>
  {{#each groupItems}}
    {{someItemtext}}
  {{/each}}
  </li>
{{/each}}
```